# inset div to contain scroll only

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I need to have a page with 3 main sections; Header, Footer and Content.  I want the footer, ONLY the footer, to scroll horizontally.  The other sections will contain static information (A Map and Chart).

Below is the code.  I was hoping to see a scroll bar in only the green box!  What am I missing?

```css
    
    #Header {
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    #Footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 180px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #Footer_Inset {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 3000px;
        overflow-style: scrollbar;
        height: 160px;
        border: 2px solid Green;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    
        <div id="Header"></div>
        <div id="Footer">
    
            <div id="Footer_Inset"></div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Header">static content</div>
<div id="Footer">
    static content
    <div id="Footer_Inset">
        <div id="Footer_Content">scrollable horizontally</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#Header {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#Footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#Footer_Inset {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 160px;
    border: 2px solid Green;
}

#Footer_Content {
    width: 3000px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxh9qyf0/)

Comment: I edited this to add some static content on the left of the scrolling section - but I get a small blank box below that (to the left of the scroll bar).  Any clues/hints:  http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/dxh9qyf0/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you should add `overflow-x: scroll` to `#Footer` and remove `overflow-style: scrollbar` from `#Footer_Inset`.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response...  I tried what you suggested - it did not work.  Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/tkj1ften/  I would like the scroll bar to appear only inside the Green Box (and only that section to scroll).

Comment: Ah, this should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/5r6yqssk/. `position: fixed` was causing some issues with overflow so needed to be removed. Also, you'll need a container inside #Footer_Inset like the example.

Comment: Yeah that's it - thanks for the clarification on position!  BTW, there is a second scroll bar (outside the blue box) in the solution you provided - any idea how to hide that?

Comment: Yeah, that's a box model/positioning issue. As you've positioned the header absolutely and then adding a 1px border it's extending just beyond the viewport hence the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ds1hc4L3/

Try putting the overflow inside `#Footer` instead of `Footer_Inset`

I also had problems with `position: fixed` for `#Footer_Inset`.  Since `#Footer` is already fixed, using static positioning seems to look ok for me.

```
    #Header {
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    #Footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 180px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        overflow-x: auto;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #Footer_Inset {
        width: 3000px;
        height: 160px;
        border: 2px solid Green;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this got the behavior I needed.  However, a second scroll bar is added to the bottom of the page - It is outside the footer div (Blue Box).  How can i hide that - Is this controlled by a page or body div?

Comment: I'd try `body { width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }`

Answer (score 1):

In `#Footer` change to `overflow-x: auto;`. Remove `position: fixed;` from `#Footer_Inset`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/uh53xejm/

```
#Header {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#Footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#Footer_Inset {
    bottom:10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 3000px;
    height: 160px;
    border: 2px solid Green;
    display: block;
}
```